# I am having issues with my header file and implementation file in c++

Tags: c++

So I am creating a basic layout for a game and I have very little experience with separating classes from my main file and making two new files out of it (implementation file, .h file). I somehow messed up with some of the separation and I can't figure out where exactly I went wrong. I also am having trouble figuring out how to go about creating an object from these two new files in my main. for example, I will show you the ORIGINAL class, then my .h then my .cpp.

******ORIGINAL CLASS******

```
class Character{

public:
    string name;
    int health;

    Character(){
        setName("Unknown Caster");
        setHealth(20);
    }
    Character(string name, int health){
        setName(name);
        setHealth(health);
    }
    void setName(string x){
        cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        name = x;  
    }
    int setHealth (int health){
        if(health < 0){
            health = 0;
        }
        this-> health = health;
        return health;
    }
    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
};
```

*****END OF ORIGINAL CLASS*****

*****START OF .h FILE*****

```
#ifndef Character_h
#define Character_h
using namespace std;

class Character{

public:
    string name;
    int health;

    Character();///default constructor

    Character(string name, int health);

    void setName(string x){  
    }

    int setHealth (int health){
    }

    string getName(){
        return name;
    }
};

#endif
```

*****END OF .h FILE*****

*****START OF .cpp FILE*****

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Character.h"


Character::Character(){
    setName("unknown caster");
    setHealth(20);
    }

Character::Character(){
    setName(name);
    setHealth(health);
    }
void Character::setName(){
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    name = x;
}

int Character::setHealth(){
    if(health < 0){
        health = 0;
    }
    this-> health = health;
        return health;
}
string Character::getName(){
    return name;
}
```

****END OF .cpp FILE*****

My code was running relatively smoothly before I separated the one class into two different files, so I am inclined to believe that I did it incorrectly. My questions are: What did I do wrong? and how do I go about making an object from this class in my main? Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Don't put `using namespace std;` in header files.

Comment: Have a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329).

Comment: Whats with the empty function bodies in the header file?  A function declaration should look like `void setName(string x);` not `void setName(string x) {}`

Comment: What errors are you getting? They should give you a hint at what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you split out the header and cpp, don't leave any definitions in the header, for example these

```
void setName(string x){  
}

int setHealth (int health){
}

string getName(){
    return name;
}
```

should be

```
void setName(string x);
int setHealth (int health);
string getName();
```

Just because you emptied out all of the code between `{` and `}`, what you ended up doing is defining these functions to essentially do no work. Then you tried to *redefine* them again in the cpp file.

Comment: Thank you! I now only have 2 errors and they say "undefined reference to Character::Character and Character::getName()" In my main to try and create a "Character" object I wrote "Character character" then from there I tried to access my functions that were inside of my .cpp file but nothing is working. This brings me to my last question that I had about separating class files and that is how to go about declaring my "Character" objects in main?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining functions in the class twice, which counts as two defined functions that have the same name, return type and parameters, which is an error.

Declaration:

```
type func_name(parameter_type , parameter_type);
```

Definition:

```
type func_name(parameter_type name, parameter_type name2) {
    //code
}
```

You want to declare once and define once per program.

Comment: I know this was from a while ago, but thank you so much!